# use identical query parameter in every endpoint of a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am building a web API. One of my controllers has several endpoints and all of them use the exact same query parameter. Is there some way to define that query parameter without touching every single method signature?

Code example:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using ProductWebAPI.Model;
using ProductWebAPI.Services;

namespace ProductWebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ProductController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<ProductController> _logger;

        public ProductController(ILogger<ProductController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "Method1")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Method1([FromQuery] string dataUrl)
        {
            //...
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "Method2")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Method2([FromQuery] string dataUrl)
        {
            //...
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "Method3")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Method3([FromQuery] string dataUrl)
        {
            //...
        }

        [HttpGet(Name = "Method4")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Product>> Method4([FromQuery] string dataUrl)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I want to avoid putting `[FromQuery] string dataUrl` in every method signature.

Comment: An example of what you have would be nice. It's too easy to make incorrect assumptions about it if we can't see code that exemplifies the problem.

Comment: It does, especially because that detail tells me that what I was considering suggesting wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: @madreflection what detail? I honestly can't think of a way to misinterpret my question. Sure, I wrote it, but I'm still curious where I was unclear.

Comment: No, you misunderstood my comment. I'm saying that the detail you provided was enough to rule out a suggestion I might have made, thus preventing an answer that would not have solved your problem.

Comment: @madreflection I understood that. but my code example is just a written out example of what I described above. I want to know why my description was not enough to understand why your solution would not help.

Comment: I wouldn't do this personally but considering they're all GETs with the only (obvious) difference being the endpoint, you could have a single route with `dataUrl` and `MethodName` query params and then delegate the calls based on that name. Sounds horrible.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yeah, I agree, that sounds horrible.

Comment: *"why my description was not enough to understand why your solution would not help"* - This is not at all what I said!

Comment: @madreflection well, you did ask for clarification in the form of a code example. why would you ask for that, if not for my description being lackluster?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I thought maybe you had multiple parameters that were repeated on each method. The code showed that I was wrong there. Suggesting that you wrap them in a class and put `[FromQuery]` on that parameter (which makes all properties of the class query string parameters) would not have solved the problem because you've shown that they only have one parameter.

Comment: @madreflection Okay, I can see how you reached that interpretation, and now I know what to include in future descriptions more clearly. thanks

Comment: I must point out, though, that `[FromQuery]` is entirely unnecessary if they are all, in fact, GETs. That attribute can be used to override its location and/or its name, but you're doing neither in the code you've posted.

Comment: @madreflection I like it for the clarity. there's no guessing where that parameter comes from.

Comment: That's fair and sensible.